# decoding PDF page stream(I don't know specific name)

Tags: pdf

I'm looking for how to decode pdf page stream(as title I don't know specific name).

It looks like this

```
/OC /MC0 BDC ./Artifact <</O /Layout >>BDC .BT./CS0 cs 0.075 0.463 0.78  scn./GS0 gs./T1_0 1 Tf.18.75 0 0 18.75 40.1772 552.638 Tm.[(AF t)15(oolkit )]TJ.ET.EMC ./Artifact <</O /Layout >>BDC .BT./T1_1 1 Tf.18.75 0 0 18.75 140.6188 552.638 Tm.[(Det)15(ect, Pr)25(ot)15(ect a
```

I could find some keywords(BT, Tm, etc) in google.
However, I can't find antoher keywords like /OC, /MC0 BDC ...

So, ***anyone know how it works for all keywords?***

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should simply look up the *specification*, i.e. ISO 32000. Adobe published a copy of the first version, ISO 32000-1:2008, on their web site to download for free. In this copy the ISO page headers have been replaced (so you may not use it for audits etc) but the technical contents are untouched. Simply google for PDF32000, currently it's at https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf but that may not be a permalink.

Be aware, though, that some of the words you're looking for are names which are defined in your pdf itself. E.g. in your

```
/OC /MC0 BDC
    ...
EMC
```

the **MC0** is an arbitrary name in the resources of your content stream, so googling for that name or searching it in the specification won't help. Instead search for the instructions, **BDC** and **EMC** here, the explanations for which will tell how to interpret those names.

But actually this example also illustrates an exception from the advice above because the name **OC** is special, so searching for it will help you along.

*In this example the **BDC** and **EMC** pair of instructions envelop* marked content, *which here is used to define* optional content *(thus, the **OC** name) while the name **MC0** simply is the name of the properties resource that describes the optional content group in question.*